# In selenium there is one test case i want to test this test case with different version of chrome browser how to do this?

Tags: selenium

Day before yesterday I had an interview , they asked to me how to test a test case with different version of chrome browser?

Comment: go for saucelabs or browserstack

Answer (score 0):

```
public WebDriver setBrowserVersion(String version){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    caps.setCapability("version", version);
    WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(caps);
WebDriver wd;
    }
```

To use this method the mentioned version should be installed in your local

or you can selenium grid to achieve your requirement. First set up your selenium grid and then use below code to initiate your driver

**Code:**

```
@Parameter({"browser","version"})
public void setBrowser(String browser,String version){

                   DesiredCapabilities dr=null;

                   if(browser.equals("chrome")){

                   dr=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

                   dr.setBrowserName("firefox");

                   dr.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
dr.setVersion(version);



                   RemoteWebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new     URL(http://localhost:4444/wd/hub), dr);

}
```

**Related Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="GRID SAMPLE TEST" thread-count="2">

    <test name="GRID TEST ">

    <parameter name ="browser" value="chrome"/>
 <parameter name ="version" value="30"/>

        <classes>

            <class name ="GridExample"/>

        </classes>

    </test>



    <test name="GRID TEST WITH diff version ">

    <parameter name ="browser" value="chrome"/>
 <parameter name ="version" value="33"/>


        <classes>
            <class name ="GridExample"/>

        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

To test in different versions of chrome you first need different versions of chrome binary present in your system.

For those different versions of chrome, you need to have the compatible chrome driver. It is recommended that you use properly supported chrome driver for each chrome version.

Then, you have to have different chrome options for different versions. When you use them in the test, initiate the chrome driver with your different chrome options for different chrome versions.

My examples are in java.

Try:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions(); 
chromeOptions.setBinary("Path to the binary of desired version of chrome");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to appropirate chrome driver binary");

WebDriver driver = ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

> Note: Setting version in capability as shown in the previous answer
>   won't change the actual chrome binary version.